# PLSQL STORED PROCEDURE does not give result

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
select count(*) 
INTO countExceed 
from uid_emp_master k 
where k.unique_id in (select k.reviewer_uid 
                      from uid_rm_hierarchy k 
                      where k.unique_id in ('||p_ID_list||')) 
                      and k.band IN( 'A','B','C','D');

if (countExceed > 0) then 
    quer :='UPDATE UID_RM_HIERARCHY I 
            SET I.REVIEWER_UID in (SELECT L.REVIEWER_UID 
                                   FROM UID_RM_HIERARCHY L 
                                   WHERE L.UNIQUE_ID  in ('||p_ID_list||') )  
            WHERE I.REVIEWER_UID in('||p_ID_list||') 
            and isdeleted=0';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  quer ;
END IF;
```

the above stored procedure does not show any result the variable countExceed declared as a number please help me to correct the query.

Comment: you need to run EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for the `select` statement as well.  I am guessing p_id_list is a variable which consists of this list, you need to make a dynamic sql for that as well.

Comment: Can you please post an example of p_ID_list? Also, how are you running this? Is this within a PL/SQL block or are you running it exactly as you posted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726467/aleksej it is plsql block

Comment: ... and p_id_list is like ... ? is it a list of comma separated list? does it contain quotes, ... ?

Comment: Comma separated list just like RAJ118831,08666F

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in 
`where k.unique_id in ('||p_ID_list||'))`

Here you are saying to look for records

`where unique_id = '||p_ID_list||'`

exactly as its typed, but what you need is to handle that variable as a list of values.

Say you have a table like this

```
create table tabTest(id) as (
    select 'id1' from dual union all
    select 'id2' from dual union all
    select 'id3' from dual union all
    select 'id4' from dual
)
```

and your input string is `'id1,id3,1d8'`;

I see two ways to do what you need; one is with dynamic SQL, for example:

```
declare
    vResult     number;
    vList       varchar2(199) := 'id1,id3,1d8';
    vSQL        varchar2(100);
begin
    vSQL := 
    'select count(*)
    from tabTest
    where id in (''' || replace (vList, ',', ''', ''') || ''')';
    --
    execute immediate vSQL into vResult;
    --
    dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || vResult);
end;
```

Another way could be by splitting the string into a list of values and then simply using the resulting list in the `IN`.

For that, there are many answers about how to split a comma separated list string in Oracle.